# Perforce, can submitted changes be shelved?

Tags: perforce

P4 version... Proxy version: P4P/LINUX26X86_64/2013.2/821990 (2014/04/08)

Let's say I made a bunch of changes and some adds, all in the default CL, then "p4 submit"ted them .  Let's say the CL generated was 12345.  Then I realized that I forgot a file, made that change, submitted it and that CL is 12346.   After all this is done, someone wants me to duplicate that work on another branch.  Would have been nice if I shelved the changes that are in 12345 and 12346 but I didn't.

Is there a way to create a new changelist that = 12345 + 12346, which is something that I can shelve and then bring into that other branch ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can do this with shelves and a lot of manual work, but what you're describing is what `p4 integrate` is for.

```
p4 integ source_branch/...@12345,12346 target_branch/...
p4 resolve -am
```

The change to `target_branch` (which consists of everything you did in changes `12345` thru `12346` on `source_branch`) is now pending in your workspace -- you can either `p4 shelve` it or just `p4 submit` it directly.